# Entity Framework 6 - SQL Server and Oracle (SaveChanges)

Tags: entity-framework-6

I have an application which uses below (Employee) domain model for SQL Server and Oracle data provider. This model works fine for Oracle data provider, however the same gives error for SQL Server. And when I change the field "**ID**" from **decimal** to **Int** it works fine for SQL Server but gives error in Oracle.

On application configuration I am changing the data provider from i.e. from SQL Server to Oracle or vice-versa.

> Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Employee' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.*
>
> ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("Emp"."Employee"."ID")

```
public class Employee
    {
        [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
        public decimal ID { get; set; }
        public string NAME { get; set; }
    }

if (ID == null || ID == 0)
{

  Model.Employee obj = new Model.Employee();
  obj.NAME = Name;
  if (Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["DataProviderType"]) == "Oracle")
     obj.ID = GetNextId();
  DbContext.Employees.Add(obj);
  DbContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

**SQL Server table script**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Employee](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [NAME] [varchar](256) NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [Employee_PK] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
        [ID] ASC
    ) WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

**Oracle table script**

```
 CREATE TABLE Employee 
 (
      "ID" NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE,
      "NAME" VARCHAR2(256)
 );

 CREATE UNIQUE INDEX "PK_Employee" ON "Employee" ("ID");
ALTER TABLE "Employee" ADD CONSTRAINT "Employee_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("ID") ENABLE;
```

How can I handle this in my application i.e. in DOTNET Side?

Comment: You can't handle it differently at client side. The column should either be database generated or not. EF insert behavior depends on that, and it cannot be changed dynamically per connection.

Comment: @IvanStoev, thanks for suggestion. I have changed the datatype for ID column in sql server.

Answer (score 0):

With suggestion from @IvanStoev, I have change datatype from **int** to **numeric IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL.** in sql server. And also handled IDENTITY_INSERT error with below code,

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Employee>().Property(i => i.ID).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
```

Hope this will help someone with similar issue.